# Ant update java variable value

Tags: ant

I am new toAant, I am preparing a build process using Ant, but before build, I have to change a configuration in java file i.e.

```
public static final String HUB_URL=xyx
```

In my Java file "TestClass.java".
I want to change the value of `HUB_URL=xyz` to `HUB_URL=abc`, before compilation. Any suggestion how I can achieve this using Ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by using ANT replace task. So to your ant target you need to add

```
 <replace file="yourjavaFile" token="HUB_URL=xyx" value="HUB_URL=abc"/>
```

where token is the replacement string and value is the new string

Check this for more detailed description of replace task.
https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Please do add the task before your build task.

Answer (score 0):

open the file

```
    TestClass.java
```

change

```
  HUB_URL=xyx;
```

to

```
  HUB_URL=abc;
```

Comment: I am afraid, i am not able to explain. I want to do using ant build

Comment: write down in your ant file   <replace file="yourjavaFile" token="HUB_URL=xyx" value="HUB_URL=abc"/> .....   Check this for more detailed description of replace task. ......https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: @SachinChauhan mark it as answered, if it solved your problem :) Give the credits to the guy below me who answered.